How can i access another class Variable while avoiding circular import?
Small introduction:
Hello guys i've been coding in python for like 1 month with some previous coding experience in C and a bit of C#.
I've done many project so far cause i think it's probably the best way to learn. While coding a Connect4 with a simple GUI made in PySide6 i've noticed that i was just using a single class for the entire project while it was probably better to divide the project in subfolders and files with their own classes.I managed to move almost every part of the project into their own subfolders and classes. Allthough now i'm struggling to do so with a simple restart button that should refresh for example "self.ui.label" inside the mainfile.
To give  a better prospective here's part of the mainWindow code where i need to modify self.ui.label
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import sys
import random

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton
from PySide6.QtCore import QTimer
from ui_form import Ui_MainWindow
from WinConPlayer.wincon import WinCondition
from Board.board import Board
from Ai.ai import Ai
from Referee.referee import Referee
from boardReset.boardReset import BoardReset

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        #Bool that will handle turns
        self.yellowTurn = False
        self.redTurn = False
        #Yellow player move coordinates
        self.coordinateX = None
        self.coordinateY = None

        #Bool to check if someone won.
        self.red_player_won = False
        self.yellow_player_won = False

        #Winner text set to blank at start.
        self.ui.label.setText("")

        #2D matrix to simulate board. We'll use this to detect winners.
        self.matrix = [
            [None, None, None, None, None, None, None], 
            [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
            [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
            [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
            [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
            [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
        ]

        #Buttons list from where we'll retrieve buttons to  enable, disable etc.
        self.buttons = [
            self.ui.b00, self.ui.b01, self.ui.b02, self.ui.b03, self.ui.b04, self.ui.b05, self.ui.b06,
            self.ui.b10, self.ui.b11, self.ui.b12, self.ui.b13, self.ui.b14, self.ui.b15, self.ui.b16,
            self.ui.b20, self.ui.b21, self.ui.b22, self.ui.b23, self.ui.b24, self.ui.b25, self.ui.b26,
            self.ui.b30, self.ui.b31, self.ui.b32, self.ui.b33, self.ui.b34, self.ui.b35, self.ui.b36,
            self.ui.b40, self.ui.b41, self.ui.b42, self.ui.b43, self.ui.b44, self.ui.b45, self.ui.b46,
            self.ui.b50, self.ui.b51, self.ui.b52, self.ui.b53, self.ui.b54, self.ui.b55, self.ui.b56
            ]


        #Call self.button assign function.
        Board.button_assign_function(self)

        #Assign restart button function.
        self.ui.restartButton.clicked.connect(BoardReset.resetBoard)

And here's the other class where we can find the resetBoard method.
from Board.board import Board
from Ai.ai import Ai

class BoardReset():

    def resetBoard(self):
        '''Function to resetBoard to 0. It can be called either by clicking or winning/drawing the game.'''
        self.ui.label.setText("")

        for button in self.buttons:
            button.setStyleSheet(("border-radius:40px; background-color:rgb(0,81,44);"))
        Board.start_game(self)
        self.matrix = [
            [None, None, None, None, None, None, None], 
            [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
            [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
            [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
            [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
            [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
        ]
        self.yellowTurn = False
        self.redTurn = False
        Board.randomTurn(self)
        if self.redTurn:
            Ai.redMove(self)

My questions are:
Now my question is. How am i supposed to call for methods like "setText" onto "self.ui.label" if i can't access self.ui.label? How can i access self.ui.label from the boardReset Class?
I've tried:
importing mainWindow into boardReset file but then i get circular import error.
And got this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/doge/DogeQt/forza4/boardReset/boardReset.py", line 8, in resetBoard
    self.ui.label.setText("")
    ^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'ui'


If you want to access self.ui in an instance of a class, then you would normally set it in the __init__ method, i.e. self.ui = ui.  You never set it, so the attribute doesn't exist in an instance of that class.

Trying to import the main window class wouldn't make sense, as you should be using the instance; trying to import the instance would also be probably discouraged (but since you're not showing how you actually create any of the instances, it's difficult to tell what would be wrong). Your usage of BoardReset is also invalid, since you're not creating an instance, and therefore resetBoard behaves similar to a function (or a static method), and the self you get is actually the argument of the clicked signal, which is also why you get that error.

There could be many ways to "fix" your problem (for instance, changing to connect(lambda: BoardReset.resetBoard(self))), but the reality is that your code has various issues to begin with, starting from the fact that you don't seem to be using that separate class as an actual class (as said, no instantiation), and it's also unclear why you need to use a separate file and class to begin with. It seems you haven't completely understood what classes/instances are, how they work and how they should be used, so my suggestion would be to take a small step back and do some research about basic OOP.

I'll start by saying you're almost right about everything. To answer your question, the reason why i wanted to use separate files and classes is because the project would be more well organized. Using just one class makes just everything messy imo. Anyway you're right about classes and instances. I know something about classes but it's not enough for sure. I think i'll make some project just to focus on classes/istances, inheritance and so on. Grazie :D

@M1dn4z Using separate classes and files is perfectly fine, but it has to be done appropriately: when it logically makes sense to have what you separate somewhere else. If a function is strictly related to a class or its instances then it should most certainly be kept within that class, which is what you should do with resetBoard, since it mostly uses the main window instance and its widgets; moving it in a different class makes little sense, it's like cooking in the kitchen, but having to go to the living room just to mix the ingredients. A separate class makes sense when it has a »

» specific purpose (and, usually, it only has/needs access to its own members, not those of which it is part - aka, the "parent"), in order to use a more modularization-based approach, for which each "module" is part of something, but does not directly access or manipulate "that something". Separating too much can also make implementation and debugging difficult (you waste a lot of time finding where some code is), so, code smart: 1. ensure that the hierarchy of your objects makes sense; 2. don't use too many files unnecessarily (eg, lots of files with just one or two small classes each).

@M1dn4z PS: remember to use @username for replies when more than one users participates in comments, otherwise we won't receive notifications.

@musicamante ty! I'll keep everything in mind
